# Excel VBA: message box to show list of errors at the end

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I would really appreciate your help with the following. The code below searchers for blanks in Column A, highlights them, then it shows a message every time a cell has blanks with the cell location (e.g."No Value, in $A$1"). I copy these cells locations in another tab called "Results".

**I need help with the following.** I want to somehow for the message to show once with the list of cells that have blanks and their location. I do not want the message to pop out every time it finds a blank cell (I could have hundreds of blank cells in a file and clicking Ok for each one is not practical). Then that list of values will be copied in my "Results" sheet.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
Sub CeldasinInfo()

Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String

coltoSearch = "A"

For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
    If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then
         r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
          r.Select
          MsgBox "No Value, in " & r.Address
          Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Sheets("Results").Range("A" &   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Formula = r.Address
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thank so much in advance. I would really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Are the cells actually empty, or do they contain a formula that results in ""?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub CeldasinInfo()

Dim i As Long, r As Range, coltoSearch As String
Dim Result as String
Dim ErrCount as integer

ErrCount = 0
coltoSearch = "A"
coltoSearch = Range("1:1").find(What:="Hours", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

Result = "No Value in:" & vbcrlf
For i = 1 To Range(coltoSearch & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set r = Range(coltoSearch & i)
    If Len(r.Value) = 0 Then
         r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
          r.Select
'          MsgBox "No Value, in " & r.Address
          Result = Result & r.Address & vbcrlf
          ErrCount = ErrCount + 1
          if ErrCount Mod 10 = 0 then    'change to 15 or 20 or whatever works well
            MsgBox Result
            Result = "No Value in:" & vbcrlf
          End If
          Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Sheets("Results").Range("A" &   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Formula = r.Address
    End If
Next

If ErrCount > 0 then
  MsgBox "There were " & ErrCount & " errors detected." & vbcrlf & result
else
  MsgBox "No errors detected"
End If
End Sub
```

This will give you each address on a separate line in the `MsgBox`. If there are hundreds of errors likely, this will result in a *very* long `MsgBox` output, and I'm not sure how it will handle that. You may need to add in a counter and display the message every 10, 15 or 20 errors for a better looking output.

Comment: Thank you!!! this works great. Yes, I understand what you mean about the list of results been very long. How do I add that counter you were mentioning?, just in case :)

Comment: Added in `ErrCount` code. The `Mod` arithmetic operator returns the remainder of division, if the remainder is 0 then that means it divided evenly. The bonus here is that you can display the total number of errors found in your final `MsgBox` at the end (which is still needed to display the last few errors).

Comment: This is great!, thank you so much again. Last question, I just thought of something. What if I am not sure about the column I want to apply the code to. Let's say I do not know if the values will be in column A, I want to first find the column that has the title "Hours" and apply the code to that column. It is because the information is not organized the same way for every scenario, and I want to find a practical way to do it without having to always change the column in "coltoSearch". Thanks

Comment: I've added a line to set `coltoSearch` based on a search for "hours" in row 1. If that's not the correct row, then change the `1:1` portion. If that may vary, you may need to make it a parm to the `Sub()` and pass it in.

Comment: Thank you. It gives me an error saying: "Object variable or With Block variable not set". Sorry to bother you about this, I am new to VBA.

Comment: Now it shows me error 400 :s. Try it on your end. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Since this has fixed your original question, please post the new code & the new error as a new question. That is standard SO policy to help make it easier for others to find questions and answers instead of having to dig through comments to track them down. It will also make it easier for us to identify the new problem.

Comment: Sure, just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

If your cells are truly blank you can avoid a range loop and use `SpecialCells`

```
Sub CeldasinInfo()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim coltoSearch As String

coltoSearch = "A"

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Columns(coltoSearch).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
MsgBox "No Value, in " & rng1.Address

End Sub
```